# Thailand coup: Lao - Thailand border closing?

Tags: thailand, borders, laos, event-based-effects

As martial law has been established in Thailand, is it possible that frontiers with neighboring countries (like Laos) would be closed to tourists?

We heard rumors about a possible closing, but I have been able to find very little information about this, [confirming only this for Lao citizens](http://news.xinhuanet.com/english/world/2014-05/23/c_133356461.htm).

Officially, crossing the border is not prohibited to foreigners, but even if it  would be authorized to cross the Friendship Bridge anyway, is it a good idea to go there now as security measures must be drastic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article in Khaosod](http://en.khaosod.co.th/detail.php?newsid=1400820590&section=11&typecate=06), a major Thai newspaper, states that all Thai-Lao border crossings have been closed to Thais going to Laos and "foreigners are not permitted to enter".  However, [this feed](http://asiancorrespondent.com/122874/thailand-coup-live/) claims that while Lao nationals are not allowed to enter Thailand, the border remains open for all others, including foreigners crossing both ways.  The situation remains fluid and this answer is likely to be outdated within days or not hours.

In general, all sides during previous coups have gone out of their way to make way for tourists, so I wouldn't expect any major problems.  The 2010 Bangkok airport occupation was an exception, and it had such a massive backlash for the organizers that it's unlikely to be repeated.